# Struts2-Rest: Manual HTTP 5xx doesn't return content

Tags: java, rest, struts2, http-headers, struts2-rest-plugin

I'm attempting to manually return a HTTP 4xx or 5xx with a custom error message. It works perfectly for GET but returns empty content for PUT and POST. Thank you in advance to anyone who can suggest how to get the PUT and POST working!

These are the calls I'm making to the webservice:
`GET /webapp/orders/A.json` - returns HTTP 500 and the error message as content
`PUT /webapp/orders/A.json` - returns HTTP 500 and content-length=0

`getModel()` is called in both instances, the message just doesn't make it back to Chrome for PUT.

Here's sample code that produces the error:

**OrdersController**

```
package com.test.controller;

import org.apache.struts2.rest.DefaultHttpHeaders;
import org.apache.struts2.rest.HttpHeaders;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Namespace;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ModelDriven;

@Namespace("/rest")
public class OrdersController implements ModelDriven<Object> {

    // GET /orders/A
    public HttpHeaders show() {
        return new DefaultHttpHeaders().withStatus(500);
    }

    // PUT /orders/A
    public HttpHeaders update() {
        return new DefaultHttpHeaders().withStatus(500);
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        // Nothing
    }

    public Object getModel() {
        return new String("{ \"message\": \"An error occurred.\"}");
    }

}
```

**Struts**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.suffix" value="Controller"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches" value="true"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="rest-default"/>
    <constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="controller"/>    
</struts>
```

**Web**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="starter" version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Orders</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>action2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>action2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**AngularJS Test Harness**

```
var orderApp = angular.module('orderApp', []);

orderApp.run(function($http) {
    $http.get("rest/orders/A.json");
    $http.put("rest/orders/A.json", {"orderId":"A"} );
});
```

Environment: Struts2 (2.3.16.3), Rest-Plugin, Convention, Java7, Tomcat7, Maven

Comment: +1, nice first question

Comment: You can do it if you add the second parameter in the url like `PUT /orders/1/???`

Comment: @RomanC Would you please elaborate? Sending `PUT /webapp/orders/1.json/aa` to the webservice results in `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.test.controller.OrdersController.aa()`.

Comment: This `{ message: \"An error occurred.\"}` is not correct json.

Comment: @AleksandrM I assume you are referring to the lack of double-quotes around "message". Thank you, I have corrected that line to `return new String("{ \"message\": \"An error occurred.\"}");`  Unfortunately, PUT still returns content-length=0.

Comment: I don't understand, first you say *It works perfectly for GET*, how do you want it to work for PUT?

Comment: @RomanC I expect an identical response for both GET and PUT: HTTP 500 with `{ "message": "An error occurred." }` in the response content. GET does this. PUT returns HTTP 500 but no content.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `<constant name="struts.rest.content.restrictToGET" value="false"/>` to struts.xml solved the problem. Kudos to @ontk for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9403583/4159927) answer to another question.  Thanks to everyone who tried to help me out.